# I can't create a tunnel between two rooms

Tags: python, game-development

I'm as making a script for one gererator dungeon for my game

```
import random
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
import tcod

from Gamemap import GameMap
import tile_types


class RectangularRoom:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, width: int, height: int):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + width
        self.y2 = y + height

    @property
    def inner(self) -> Tuple[slice, slice]:
        """Return the inner area of this room as a 2D array index."""
        return slice(self.x1 + 1, self.x2), slice(self.y1 + 1, self.y2)

def tunnel_between(
    start: Tuple[int, int], end: Tuple[int, int]
) -> Iterator[Tuple[int, int]]:
    """Return an L-shaped tunnel between these two points."""
    x1, y1 = start
    x2, y2 = end
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        corner_x, corner_y = x2, y1
    else:
        corner_x, corner_y = x1, y2
    for x, y in tcod.los.bresenham((x1, y1), (corner_x, corner_y)).tolist():
        yield x, y
    for x, y in tcod.los.bresenham((corner_x, corner_y), (x2, y2)).tolist():
        yield x, y

def generate_dungeon(map_width, map_height) -> GameMap:
    dungeon = GameMap(map_width, map_height)

    room_1 = RectangularRoom(x=20, y=15, width=10, height=15)
    room_2 = RectangularRoom(x=35, y=15, width=11, height=19)

    dungeon.tiles[room_1.inner] = tile_types.floor
    dungeon.tiles[room_2.inner] = tile_types.floor

    for x, y in tunnel_between(room_2.center, room_1.center):
        dungeon.tiles[x, y] = tile_types.floor

    return dungeon
```

but, is giving this error

```
File "C:\Users\JOAO\PycharmProjects\pythings\venv\ProtoRED\procgen.py", line 45, in generate_dungeon
    for x, y in tunnel_between(room_2.center, room_1.center):
AttributeError: 'RectangularRoom' object has no attribute 'center'
```

i am trying to solve this problem for a while but, nothing is helping. Not even rewriting the entire code, can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless I am misinterpreting; you don't appear to have a property called `center` on `RectangularRoom`? Only `x1,x2,y1,y2`. Add a property for `center` and calculate what that would be based on your values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need a `.center` property

I think it needs to be a Tuple of 2 integers.

```
class RectangularRoom:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, width: int, height: int):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + width
        self.y2 = y + height
        self.center = (int(x + width/2), int(y + height/2))
```